# How to default social media status to "Available"?

Tags: default

Is there any way to default the below picture to "Available", so I don't have to remember (I never do) to manually change it every time. I end up never utilizing Ubuntu's features because I always forget to do this.

Any help appreciated!

[image]

How to change it ?